# Django and Spatialite crash

Tags: django, dump, spatialite

I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/gis/install/#spatialdb-template) to add Spatialite to my django app, but, when I try to run syncdb all crash.

Here is the only model that uses geographical points:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models


class Building(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    versione = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    indirizzo = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    numero_di_piani = models.IntegerField()
    data_creazione = models.DateTimeField('data creazione', blank=True)
    data_update = models.DateTimeField('data update', blank=True)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='buildings', blank=True)
    pronto = models.BooleanField()

    # Geo Django field to store a point
    posizione = models.PointField(help_text="Represented as (longitude, latitude)", unique=True)

    # Geo Django area dell'edificio
    # area =  models.PolygonField(unique=True)

    # You MUST use GeoManager to make Geo Queries
    objects = models.GeoManager()       

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.nome
```

Here is the error throwed by syncdb:

```
*** glibc detected *** /usr/bin/python: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0xb6154f98 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x72132)[0x326132]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x72378)[0x326378]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0(+0x10d1e)[0x493d1e]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0(sqlite3_free+0x81)[0x495461]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0(+0x13068)[0x496068]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0(sqlite3_close+0x1c0)[0x4d1080]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysqlite2/_sqlite.so(pysqlite_connection_close+0x102)[0x478b52]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x14c8)[0x80f8798]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x154)[0x80fd604]
/usr/bin/python[0x808c7a2]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x51)[0x805de71]
/usr/bin/python[0x8073aad]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x51)[0x805de71]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0xcd9)[0x80f7fa9]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x930)[0x80f7c00]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x154)[0x80fd604]
/usr/bin/python[0x808c9b4]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x51)[0x805de71]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x1f3e)[0x80f920e]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x154)[0x80fd604]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x7ef)[0x80f7abf]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x154)[0x80fd604]
/usr/bin/python[0x808c7a2]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x51)[0x805de71]
/usr/bin/python[0x8073aad]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x51)[0x805de71]
/usr/bin/python[0x80c29a8]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x51)[0x805de71]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0xcd9)[0x80f7fa9]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x154)[0x80fd604]
/usr/bin/python[0x808c7a2]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x51)[0x805de71]
/usr/bin/python[0x8073aad]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x51)[0x805de71]
/usr/bin/python[0x80c29a8]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x51)[0x805de71]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0xcd9)[0x80f7fa9]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x930)[0x80f7c00]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x930)[0x80f7c00]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x154)[0x80fd604]
/usr/bin/python[0x808c9b4]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x51)[0x805de71]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x1f3e)[0x80f920e]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x154)[0x80fd604]
/usr/bin/python[0x808c7a2]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x51)[0x805de71]
/usr/bin/python[0x8073aad]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x51)[0x805de71]
/usr/bin/python[0x80c2f5a]
/usr/bin/python[0x80be55b]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x51)[0x805de71]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0xcd9)[0x80f7fa9]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x930)[0x80f7c00]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x154)[0x80fd604]
/usr/bin/python[0x808c9b4]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x51)[0x805de71]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x1f3e)[0x80f920e]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x930)[0x80f7c00]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x930)[0x80f7c00]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x154)[0x80fd604]
/usr/bin/python[0x808c7a2]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x51)[0x805de71]
/usr/bin/python[0x8073aad]
======= Memory map: ========
00110000-0029d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 270449     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
0029d000-002ab000 r--p 0018d000 08:01 270449     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
002ab000-002b1000 rw-p 0019b000 08:01 270449     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
002b1000-002b4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
002b4000-00430000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 271651     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
00430000-00432000 r--p 0017c000 08:01 271651     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
00432000-00433000 rw-p 0017e000 08:01 271651     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
00433000-00436000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00436000-00447000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1455353    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so
00447000-00448000 r--p 00010000 08:01 1455353    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so
00448000-0044b000 rw-p 00011000 08:01 1455353    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so
0044b000-0044e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1455372    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/termios.so
0044e000-0044f000 r--p 00002000 08:01 1455372    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/termios.so
0044f000-00451000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 1455372    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/termios.so
00451000-0046b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1455366    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
0046b000-0046e000 r--p 0001a000 08:01 1455366    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
0046e000-00471000 rw-p 0001d000 08:01 1455366    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
00471000-00480000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1834994    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysqlite2/_sqlite.so
00480000-00481000 r--p 00    00e000 08:01 1834994    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysqlite2/_sqlite.so
00481000-00483000 rw-p 00    00f000 08:01 1834994    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysqlite2/_sqlite.so
00483000-00521000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1447468    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
00521000-00522000 ---p 0009e000 08:01 1447468    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
00522000-00523000 r--p 0009e000 08:01 1447468    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
00523000-00524000 rw-p 0009f000 08:01 1447468    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
00524000-00525000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00525000-00541000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 262584     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
00541000-00542000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 262584     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
00542000-00543000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 262584     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
00543000-0057f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1705015    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
0057f000-00581000 r--p 0003b000 08:01 1705015    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
00581000-00583000 rw-p 0003d000 08:01 1705015    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
00583000-005a5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1447341    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
005a5000-005a6000 r--p 00022000 08:01 1447341    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
005a6000-005a7000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 1447341    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
005b3000-005bb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1705775    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/_speedups.so
005bb000-005bc000 r--p 00    007000 08:01 1705775    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/_speedups.so
005bc000-005bd000 rw-p 00    008000 08:01 1705775    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/_speedups.so
005c3000-005eb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 271669     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
005eb000-005ec000 r--p 00028000 08:01 271669     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
005ec000-005ed000 rw-p 00029000 08:01 271669     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
005ed000-00757000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1851082    /usr/local/lib/libgeos-3.4.0dev.so
00757000-0075e000 r--p 00169000 08:01 1851082    /usr/local/lib/libgeos-3.4.0dev.so
0075e000-00760000 rw-p 00170000 08:01 1851082    /usr/local/lib/libgeos-3.4.0dev.so
00760000-00761000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00761000-0076c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 271673     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
0076c000-0076d000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 271673     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
0076d000-0076e000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 271673     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
0078d000-00796000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1851093    /usr/local/lib/libfreexl.so.1.0.0
00796000-00797000 r--p 00008000 08:01 1851093    /usr/local/lib/libfreexl.so.1.0.0
00797000-00798000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 1851093    /usr/local/lib/libfreexl.so.1.0.0
007d4000-00807000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1469778    /usr/lib/libproj.so.0.6.6
00807000-00808000 r--p 00032000 08:01 1469778    /usr/lib/libproj.so.0.6.6
00808000-0080a000 rw-p 00033000 08:01 1469778    /usr/lib/libproj.so.0.6.6
00888000-0088b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1455336    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
0088b000-0088c000 r--p 00002000 08:01 1455336    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
0088c000-0088e000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 1455336    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
008a5000-00983000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1447473    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
00983000-00984000 ---p 000de000 08:01 1447473    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
00984000-00988000 r--p 000de000 08:01 1447473    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
00988000-00989000 rw-p 000e2000 08:01 1447473    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
00989000-00990000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00a77000-00a78000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
00ac3000-00ae1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 271671     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
00ae1000-00ae2000 r--p 0001d000 08:01 271671     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
00ae2000-00ae3000 rw-p 0001e000 08:01 271671     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
00b53000-00b77000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1851085    /usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.so.1.8.0
00b77000-00b78000 r--p 00023000 08:01 1851085    /usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.so.1.8.0
00b78000-00b79000 rw-p 00024000 08:01 1851085    /usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.so.1.8.0
00ba6000-00bb9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 262646     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
00bb9000-00bba000 r--p 00012000 08:01 262646     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
00bba000-00bbb000 rw-p 00013000 08:01 262646     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
00bfe000-00bff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
00d08000-00d0b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 271667     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
00d0b000-00d0c000 r--p 00002000 08:01 271667     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
00d0c000-00d0d000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 271667     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
00d86000-00d9d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 271665     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
00d9d000-00d9e000 r--p 00016000 08:01 271665     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
00d9e000-00d9f000 rw-p 00017000 08:01 271665     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
00d9f000-00da1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00df3000-00df5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 271658     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libutil-2.13.so
00df5000-00df6000 r--p 00001000 08:01 271658     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libutil-2.13.so
00df6000-00df7000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 271658     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libutil-2.13.so
00e95000-00edd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 270457     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
00edd000-00edf000 r--p 00047000 08:01 270457     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
00edf000-00ee2000 rw-p 00049000 08:01 270457     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
00f46000-00f60000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1455348    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
00f60000-00f61000 r--p 00019000 08:01 1455348    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
00f61000-00f69000 rw-p 0001a000 08:01 1455348    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
00f69000-01326000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1851113    /usr/local/lib/libspatialite.so.2.2.0
01326000-01327000 ---p 003bd000 08:01 1851113    /usr/local/lib/libspatialite.so.2.2.0
01327000-01328000 r--p 003bd000 08:01 1851113    /usr/local/lib/libspatialite.so.2.2.0
01328000-0132b000 rw-p 003be000 08:01 1851113    /usr/local/lib/libspatialite.so.2.2.0
0132b000-0132e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
08048000-0826b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1439182    /usr/bin/python2.7
0826b000-0826c000 r--p 00222000 08:01 1439182    /usr/bin/python2.7
0826c000-082c1000 rw-p 00223000 08:01 1439182    /usr/bin/python2.7
082c1000-082cd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
098d5000-0a31d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]Aborted
```

I don't know what is the problem...

Help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty old question, but best guess is that you are using an amalgamation build of spatialite, and that there are two (different) versions of sqlite loaded.

Don't ever do spatialite amalgamation builds, except on embedded platforms where you know everything about the configuration.